# PHP Curl - How to do POST request and the parameters should be in JSON format in the body

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to replicate the same POST request in PHP curl. The request parameters should be in json in the body and the response too is a json object.

[image: Fiddler sample]

```
{
"api_key": "scTrCT",
"test": "true",
"service_provider_list": [
    {
        "facility_name": "ALL YOUR SMILE NEEDS DENTAL CENTERS",
        "provider_name": "DRS. HERMAN AND MACK P.C",
        "tax_id": "12345678
    }
],
"payer_ids": [
    "00431"
],
"transaction_type": "270",
"effective_date": "2014-01-12"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php

$json = array(
    "api_key" => "scTrCT",
    "test" => "true",
    "service_provider_list" => array(
        "facility_name" => "ALL YOUR SMILE NEEDS DENTAL CENTERS",
        "provider_name" => "DRS. HERMAN AND MACK P.C",
        "tax_id" => "12345678"
    ),
    "payer_ids" => array(
        "00431"
    ),
    "transaction_type" => "270",
    "effective_date" => "2014-01-12"
);

$json = json_encode($json);

$ch = curl_init('http://gds.eligibleapi.com/v1.3/enrollment.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: That worked.. Thanks.. But when i give wrong api key, it retuned error code 22. In fiddler it returned the error description  as Invalid Api'. How do i get the description. Following is the code used to catch the error.

$error = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($error) {
  //$error_codes = $this->_get_curl_error_codes();
  echo $error;//.': '.$error_codes[$error];
  die();
}

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! And I'm glad you didn't actually put your real API key.

Comment: In the case that the API server is unavailable, you may use `if (curl_errno($ch))` right after `curl_exec`, which will indicate whether or not an issue happened during the post request. If you have errors with the response, I'm sorry but you'll need to reference the API manual.